# PHP MySQL Database Connection

Tags: php, mysql

Is it necessary to explicitly close a DB connection after executing a query (and other DB operation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, unless you're sure you've finished communicating with the database for the script run. Even then, you don't *need* to close it explicitly at all as PHP does that automatically after your script finishes executing, unless you're using [`mysql_pconnect()`](http://www.php.net/mysql-pconnect) to connect to your database.

Answer (score 3):

No, php does that automatically. You could call it "good programming practice" to clean up (aka close the connection) though.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, only close it after you have finished the database for that entire page. Also, depending on the API you are using to handle the database, most ones you should be using now (such as [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)) are implemented via Objects, so the destructor will automatically handle closing it at the end if needed.

Answer (score 0):

even though php does it automatically I can tell as much as if we didnt do it on our site, our db server would reach max_connections really really fast. So its very good practice.

Actually I would structure code like this

open conn
make all queries
close con

rest of the code

Because then slow devices wont make your connections hang.